# Why Scala for comprehension run Future functions sequentially?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

Consider the following code:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object FutureFor {
  def getA(n: Int) = {
    val x: Future[String] = Future {
      println("I'm getA")
      for (i <- 1 to 5) {
        println(".")
        Thread.sleep(200)
      }
      s"A$n"
    }
    x
  }

  def getB(n: Int) = {
    val x: Future[String] = Future {
      println("I'm getB")
      for (i <- 1 to 5) {
        println(".")
        Thread.sleep(200)
      }
      s"B$n"
    }
    x
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    println("\nThis is sequential")
    val rs1 = for {
      a <- getA(1)
      b <- getB(1)
    } yield (a + b)
    println(Await.result(rs1, 1 minute))

    println("\nThis is concurrent")
    val first = getA(2)
    val second = getB(2)
    val rs2 = for {
      a <- first
      b <- second
    } yield (a + b)

    println(Await.result(rs2, 1 minute))
  }

}
```

The output of this code is:

```
This is sequential
I'm getA
.
.
.
.
.
I'm getB
.
.
.
.
.
A1B1

This is concurrent
I'm getB
.
I'm getA
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
A2B2
```

However I would think that in both the cases the Future should execute concurrently. What is it that is making the execution sequential in the first case?

Comment: It is true for both the cases, so why it doesn't block for second case. And, `Thread.sleep` is within `Future`, so any other `Future` shouldn't wait for this one to complete. This is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It executes sequentially because `getB` won't be called but only in the callback function of the `Future` returned by `getA`. It's explained very well [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

**update**: so the `for` comprehension translates to `map`s, `flatMap`s and `filter`s, which on they turn are just [turned into callbacks](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L233) behind the scenes

Answer (score 2):

Can I just use source from [Handling futures with for-comp, but if clauses are making things difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377615/)
to try to explain how I see the problem(cause I have those source already compiled)?

this for loop:

```
for {
  a <- fooService.getA()
  b <- fooService.getB()
} println(a + b)
```

just gets desugared by scalac using map and flatMap combinators so, lets rewrite it by hand:

```
fooService.getA.foreach{ a =>
  fooService.getB.foreach{ b =>
    println(a+b)
  }
}
```

This code seems sequential. If you would have yield keyword in for comprehension,

```
for {
  a <- fooService.getA()
  b <- fooService.getB()
} yield(a + b)
```

then it would be desugared to

```
fooService.getA.map{ a =>
  fooService.getB.flatMap{ b =>
    a + b
  }
}
```

Which is also sequential. for comprehension is no more no less than combination of map/flatMap/filter